# Convert string from xmlcharrefreplace back to utf-8

Tags: python, utf-8, encode, unicode-string

I've next part of code:

```
In [8]: st = u"опа"

In [11]: st.encode("ascii", "xmlcharrefreplace")
Out[11]: '&#1086;&#1087;&#1072;'

In [14]: st1 = st.encode("ascii", "xmlcharrefreplace")

In [15]: st1.decode("ascii", "xmlcharrefreplace")
Out[15]: u'&#1086;&#1087;&#1072;'

In [16]: st1.decode("utf-8", "xmlcharrefreplace")
Out[16]: u'&#1086;&#1087;&#1072;'
```

Do you have any idea how to convert `st1` back to `u"опа"`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the [`html.unescape()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) (Python 3.4 and newer):

```
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape('&#1086;&#1087;&#1072;')
'опа'
```

On older versions (including Python 2), you’d have to use an instance of [`HTMLParser.HTMLParser()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html#HTMLParser.HTMLParser):

```
>>> from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
>>> parser = HTMLParser()
>>> parser.unescape('&#1086;&#1087;&#1072;')
u'\u043e\u043f\u0430'
>>> print parser.unescape('&#1086;&#1087;&#1072;')
опа
```

Comment: Can this answer be expanded to include specifying a target other than utf-8?  I'm writing a utility and I'd like to be able to translate html escapes into correct byte encoding schemes.  This answer is tantalizingly close.

Comment: @avgvstvs: nothing in this answer specifies a target or requires UTF-8. The function takes a `str` object, so you'll have to decode your bytes value. That's outside the scope of this question and answer, however.

Comment: So to clarify (but not waste too much time) Byte encodings that are HTML-escaped can be escaped as any charset.  I have noted that if the input here is `这` Python's escaping doesn't produce `&#00e8;&#00bf;&#0099;` and the converse operation you show here is also broken...  the solution doesn't seem to obtain for the entire UTF-8 range like I would expect.

Comment: @avgvstvs HTML escapes [encode Unicode code points](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/WD-html52-20170228/syntax.html#character-references), not bytes. It happens sometimes that *broken code* produces HTML escapes for bytes but that’s not how it is supposed to go.  Your example codepoint is [U+8FD9 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-8FD9](https://codepoints.net/U+8FD9) so it is encoded as `&#x8FD9;`.

Comment: @avgvstvs the point of HTML escapes is to *be encoding independent*.