# exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError - 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, ascii

I keep getting this error:

```
<type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
      args = ('ascii', '\xe2\x9d\xb6 Senn =)', 0, 1, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
      encoding = 'ascii'
      end = 1
      message = ''
      object = '\xe2\x9d\xb6 Senn =)'
      reason = 'ordinal not in range(128)'
      start = 0
```

Using this code:

```
    steamFriend = data['response']['players'][i]
    n = steamUser(steamFriend['personaname'].encode("utf-8"), steamFriend['steamid'], steamFriend['avatarfull'], steamFriend['profileurl'], steamFriend['personastate'], False)
```

Some things to note here:

- `steamFriend` is a JSON object
- I get this error only sometimes, because the `steamFriend['personaname']` contains some weird symbols (for example ❶), and I don't know how to parse this correctly so I don't get errors.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Also, `\xe2\x9d\xb6 Senn =)` is supposed to represent `❶ Senn =)`, if that helps.

Comment: Had a similar error once in my web scraping. The resolution was first decoding the string as ascii then encoding as utf-8. Or perhaps the other way around...

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the full code it is hard to tell, but it seems that steamUser expects ascii input. If that is the problem, you can solve it by:

```
streamFriend['personaname'].encode("ascii", errors="ignore")
```

or

```
streamFriend['personaname'].encode("ascii", errors="replace")
```

Obviously you will lose unicode characters in the process.

Comment: I don't want to lose unicode characters, so what's an alternative?

Comment: You don't have an alternative if the steamUser function expects ascii data, except perhaps to use errors="xmlcharrefreplace" which will convert the unicode characters to an ascii xml representation. You can then use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341601/convert-string-from-xmlcharrefreplace-back-to-utf-8 to convert it back to utf8 when need be. A simpler and cleaner solution, if you have control over the full code base, would be to fix the steamUser function so it can accept unicode.

Answer (score 1):

If the quoted error is occurring on the `n=...` line, the implication is that `steamFriend['personaname']` is a byte string, not a Unicode string.

Consequently when you ask to `.encode` it, Python has to **de**code the string to Unicode in order to be able to **en**code it back to bytes. An implicit decoding happens using the default encoding, which is ASCII, so because the byte string does not contain only ASCII you get a failure.

Are you sure you didn't mean to do:

```
steamFriend['personaname'].decode("utf-8")
```

**de**coding the byte string `'\xe2\x9d\xb6 Senn =)'` using UTF-8 would give you the Unicode string `u'\u2776 Senn =)'`, where U+2776=❶ so that would seem more like what you are after.

(Normally, however, JSON strings are explicitly Unicode, so it's not clear where you would have got the byte string from. How are you loading the JSON content?)

Comment: So if I decode it then I get this error `<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2776' in position 2954: ordinal not in range(128)`. What do I do now? Do I have to encode back into ascii to get the ❶?

Comment: I took out the `.encode("utf-8")` part because you're right- the JSON string is already unicode- it has a value of `u'\u2776 Senn =)'`